# How to merge two rows into one for checking the status

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table that has logtime for the User with status as 1 & 2.
If the status is 1 then it in logIn Time and if the status is 2 then it is logOut Time.

So I want to display the log In & Out time of the user. If it has no logout Time the column value should be null.

Here is a **[Sample Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cdcad/28/0)** on the table Structure and the Query...

I get the logOut time to be displayed for all logIn time......

I want the output as:

```
CLOCKIN     CLOCKOUT
9:25:41 AM  9:30:41 AM
9:35:41 AM  9:40:41 AM
9:45:41 AM  
10:06:33 AM 2:59:51 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a couple of correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT   CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),cin.logtime,108) AS CLOCKIN
        ,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20),( SELECT MIN(cout.logtime) 
                                FROM table1 cout 
                                WHERE cin.logtime < cout.logtime 
                                AND cout.statusId = 2 
                                AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table1 cin2 
                                                WHERE cin2.logtime > cin.logtime 
                                                AND cin2.logtime < cout.logtime 
                                                AND cin2.statusId = 1
                                                )
                                ),108) AS CLOCKOUT
FROM table1 cin
WHERE cin.statusId = 1
```

Most outer query gets all the checkings, first subquery (outer) gets the minimal checkout after the checkin, and second subquery (most inner) just cheks if there was a checkin afterwards - to make NULL in the third row instead of duplicate 14:59

**[SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/1cdcad/62)**

Answer (score 0):

Use style 22 for `CONVERT` function:

```
select convert (varchar (20), cast (getdate() as time) , 22)
```

or just insert this into your code:

```
 convert (varchar (20), cast (rt.rt.logTime as time ), 22)
,convert (varchar (20), cast (rt1.rt.logTime as time ), 22)
```